# Linux Software Raid Rebuild on machine failure

Tags: linux, debian, raid, mdadm

I have a debian home server that has a 4 disk software RAID 5 array. My OS runs only on a normal nvme SSD. I know thats not secure, but it is a home server, so I didn't really care when I installed it and now it is too late to change it. I was wondering what would happen to my software RAID when the OS failed (or the SSD). How could I resync (I don't know what the correct term for it is) the array to use it after I bought a new ssd and installed a new OS?

I found something regarding the mdadm config, but mine is empty... Just for clarification: this is just something I thought about to be prepared when it happens (I don't want to loose all my data)

Thanks for your answers in advance

Comment: You should have a look at the following link https://serverfault.com/questions/821966/how-to-re-add-a-drive-when-raid-is-in-degraded-mode

Comment: That is not what I meant. That would be for when I have a drive failure.
The case I meant is a OS or system failure. So what happens when I have to reinstall the os for some reason and my system data is lost. How will mdadm know how to handle those drives. I wouldn't want any data to be lost in that case

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think the mdadm config is empty ?

You should try the `mount` command to know how your volumes are mounted : mdadm devices ? LVM volumes ? Depending of the technology, the way to rebuild your volumes after a crash will be different. (My previous link is for mdadm).

The behaviour of the OS if the unmirrored SSD is faulty will depends of which files won’t be available… I have a server which a single HDD : I rebuilt it with a backup.

Usually, RAID system use metadata to verify if the disks are paired when assembling them, then adding a SSD and mirroring the first one may need an OS reinstall. This typically create the volume (and wipe it), create initramfs file to be sure the mirroring modules are available at the boot stage, etc. I don’t think there is an easy and shorter way.

Comment: the file `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` is empty. That is the config file that is referred to in many discussions

Comment: You can use the output of `mdadm --detail --scan` to create your config file.

Comment: And if I save the result and - should the system fail - create the `mdadm.conf` on a newly installed system and it works? Or do I have to do something else?

Comment: You can assemble your volume with `mdadm --assemble --scan` Or reboot your server. This reload the `mdadm.conf` file.